# Is there any open source wrapper around UnityEngine.GL namespace that would provide System.Drawing.Graphics alike intereface?

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, unity-game-engine, system.drawing

I would love to see [`System.Drawing.Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like `DrawPath(pen, path)`, `TranslateTransform(dx, dy, order)`, `ScaleTransform(sx, sy, order)` wrapped around 
[`UnityEngine.GL`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GL.html) (or at least some other OpenGL library to create my own port). Is there any such wrapper/library?

Comment: what language are you using? isn't it c#?

Comment: @j-p: yes it is C#, .NET 3.5. Also I found [one wrapper - filipkunc / GLGraphics](https://github.com/filipkunc/GLGraphics). yet it is in CLI and for pure OpenGL - not Unity3d.GL =(

Comment: this lib (glgraphics) is very far from something usable, checking the code, there is no line joints, which is (with fast glyph rendering),one of the big problem in opengl vector rendering. I use cairo, the wrapper is Mono.Cairo, Mono System.Drawing implementation use cairo internaly, but it's state mechanism is quite easy to use. It's accelerated on egl surfaces, and I'm currently studying how to have it handle drawing calls on the gpu (if it isn't already done) (I'm stuck trying to have a clean egl context with my r600 ati chipset.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to draw on a texture to use in unity, here is the simpliest example using [cairo](http://cairographics.org/) to build a bitmap directely usable for texturing with opengl. the wrapper is [Mono.Cairo](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo)

```
using System;
using Cairo;

namespace cairoTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            int height = 512;
            int width = 512;
            int stride = 4 * width; 

            int bmpSize = stride * height;
            byte[] bmp = new byte[bmpSize];

            using (ImageSurface surf =
                new ImageSurface(bmp, Format.Argb32, width, height, stride))
            {
                using (Context ctx = new Context(surf))
                {
                    ctx.SetSourceRGB(1, 0, 0);
                    ctx.Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
                    ctx.Fill();
                }
                surf.Flush();
                //surf.WriteToPng(@"c:/test.png");
            }
            //now you have bmp filled, and may pass it to your game engine as texture             
        }
    }
}
```

Next step would be to create an egl context and try to keep all the work on the gpu, passing your final texture just as you bind an already existing one.